# Was creating 'low-abv' tag wise?

Tags: discussion, tags

I could not find any tag specific to low/non-alcohol brewing in my question: [Is removing alcohol to create low/non alcoholic wine/beer feasible for the home brewer?](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/25769/is-removing-alcohol-to-create-low-non-alcoholic-wine-beer-feasible-for-the-home)

So I have created `low-abv` - I think this is reasonable alongside the existing `alcohol-content` tag as it is a whole niche in itself, but how does the community feel about it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this could be valuable since, as you said in your question, low-ABV beers are becoming increasingly popular.  I could see people having concerns about contamination, dry-hopping, bottling, etc. that could be specific to brewing low-ABV beers.

It might not be a bad idea to add a tag wiki excerpt that better defines the intention (e.g. including/excluding non-alcoholic beers), but that's always something that can be added/refined as new questions come in and we see what users do with it.